# Search for any word EXCEPT specific ones?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace words with plurals. I know there are multiple plural stems but for now just doing the basic 's'. I also get that I can make a # of word-ending cases. For my purposes right now I'd simply like to do:

```
(\w+\b)
```

but have it ignore either:

- Specific words
- Words that end in specific letter(s)

So for instance if I had it ignore `\w+dy\b (e.g. Study)` and ignore specifically the words Title|Body it would find ANY word except *dy, Title, Body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have lookahead support you can use this regex:

```
\b(?!(Title|\w*?dy)\b)\w+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN2aD5/1)

`Body` ends with `dy` so no need to add it in exception list.